# Computational power of superluminal signaling TM

Tags: computational-complexity, computability, oracles

Good day to everyone,
I would love to ask You a question about the computational power of a hypothetical Turing machine.

Lets imagine a world, where the laws of physics don't prohibit FTL communication and there exists a mean of instantaneous communication across arbitrary distance. What would be a computational power of TM inside such world?

I know that this question is vague, but I got into an argument with a friend of mine who believes in ESP (extra senzory perception) where one can send thought instantaneously across arbitrary distance. Now I am skeptic when it comes to ESP, but I wonder how would such phenomena increase the computational possibilities. Could computers (modeled by TM) in such hypothetical scenario reach nontrivially into Arithmetical hierarchy? Encompass it whole? Reach nontrivially into projective hierarchy?

Thank You for kind answers.

Comment: A Turing machine is a mathematical object, not a physical object, so the physical possibilities are irrelevant in this sense. But of course, this is probably inspired by quantum computation. What happens on the mathematical side in this context is not that Turing machines can do more, but that we have a different computation model we use that reflects the new physical possibilities not accounted for by Turing machines. (And fwiw quantum computation models result in the same class of computable functions… the difference is all in questions of computational complexity.)

Comment: @spaceisdarkgreen ok I think I understand but more practically what could people compute in such world with their quantum universal computer where entanglement allows instantaneous information transfer?

Comment: They could compute the same things but faster

Answer (score 1):

It would probably be able to compute the same thing as a classical Turing Machine (the same laws apply to the atomic steps of computation) but everything can be computed in constant time as FTL communication means you can send message in the past.

So just send the result in the past once its computed. But you still need to spend energy and time for the computation after the result is received (otherwise, it's a paradox, but then, you wouldn't have received any result).

Comment: so it wouldn't lead to any hypercomputation? That seems strange, because Abrams and Lloyd showed, that nonlinear qunatum mechanics implies one could solve NP-complete and #P-complete problems in polynomial time which itself is Hypercomputation. So I had the impression that the power of superluminally signaling TM would be between nonlinear QM TM and Hamkins ITTM

Comment: @PanMrož Quantum mechanics allow, in some way, unbounded number of states to be computed simultaneously. But FTL doesn't do any special computation to my knowledge.

Comment: $\#\textsf{P}$ is contained in $\textsf{FPSPACE}$ (the set of functions that are $\textsf{PSPACE}$-computable). And $\textsf{FPSPACE}$ is much weaker than $\textsf{Arithmetic Hierarchy}$.